# Not able to use custom fonts in .Net MAUI WebView

Tags: android, webview, fonts, maui

I have a Xamarin Android application that I am modifying to .Net MAUI, in which I use a WebView control that displays some HTML content. I am using a custom font. Before I added this line to the HTML header and it worked fine on Xamarin

```
@font-face{font-family:Simplified; 
src: url('file:///android_asset/Fonts/Simplified.ttf')}
```

I am doing the same on .Net MMUI, but it didn’t work, and I am getting this error message in the output during debugging:

```
[AndroidProtocolHandler] Unable to open asset URL: file:///android_asset/Fonts/Simplified.ttf
```

One final thing is that on Xamarin, I placed the font in the folder
`\ProjectName.Android\Assets\Fonts\Simplified.ttf`
Build Action: AndroidAsset
Copy To Output Directory: Copy Always

In MAUI, I placed the file in the folder:
`\Platforms\Android\Fonts\Simplified.ttf`

I tied to place the font in many different places and changed the path of the font by keeping only the filename, but nothing worked.

Comment: How did you do it in xamarin ? Are you using a custom renderer to achieve this, just as [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3d21124d-62f0-4ee9-9e4b-d3c220a0df25/set-custom-font-in-webview?forum=xamarinforms) mentioned? If so, you can also implement it in MAUI. Please check document [Using Custom Renderers in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Using-Custom-Renderers-in-.NET-MAUI).